What does make a good [career] question, and should they be allowed?
Something that I've noticed is that [career] questions, about Information Security careers, have substantially the largest close to open ratio of any other question (tag) that has more than a few questions. A SEDE query revealed that there is 33 open [career] questions and 70 closed ones. So about 70%.

Now, I've read the question what makes a good [career] question, and according to Rory's answer:

"What should I study to get into security?" "How can I get into security?" "What is the ideal path to security?" "What are the job prospects?"

are all "terrible questions". This makes perfect sense because most I've read do appear to be opinion-based and/or can't be answered with a definitive answer.
This answer a great job at summing up a bad [career] question, but still doesn't actually answer what a good one looks like.
So,

What makes a good [career] question?

and

Should [career] questions actually be allowed, considering the amount that get closed?


Do the analysis. Of the non-closed questions where hi-rep people answer, what are the common elements?

@schroeder hmm, that is quite a good idea. I’ll take a better look now. However, it does seem the case that a lot of the higher voted [career] questions are a fair bit older… maybe the good ones already taken.

And the age of the answered ones are a factor. With some analysis, we might be able to determine if we do need to close the tag. Career questions that are purely fact-based may be few and far between, but let's see.

@schroeder after even more 'research', it seems that back when the was young, more career questions that would be closed off-topic (e.g. opinion bases, not in scope etc.) now, got a high score back then when the rules were less rigid, you could say.

And then there's handful, literally maybe 3-4, of good ones that wouldn't be closed as off-topic even now, but there is a ridiculous amount of dupes stemming to the same questions again and again.

Which leads me back to my first problem with the tag: if an answer can't be objective throughout many 'scenarios', then answers only apply to the person who asked them meaning that A) it isn't useful for anyone else, and B) said question is really hard to identify as a dupe from a non dupe.

And that's good info. And yes, rules were more lax 10 years ago as we tried to figure out where a reasonable line would be and we learned as we went. What we might do is come up with a canonical answer for the common dupes, and flag the tag as likely off-topic.

@schroeder That does sound like quite a good idea. I've seen that a lot of questions that have a high amount of upvotes, and have been taken really well (comments, answers etc.) but are now off-topic. I believe many of these are "locked for historical significance", or something like that.
